# Symfony 3 equivalents in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

What is Symfony 3 *view* equivalent to in Symfony 4? I am building a basic todo list app using Symfony 4. I cannot find the resources directory in Symfony 4 to create a view.

Comment: Put your views in templates directory

Comment: And strictly as a last resort: [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#template-naming-and-locations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general:

Symfony 3's `.../app/Resources/views` directory is replaced by Symfony 4's `.../templates`. If there are other directories in `.../app/Resources` the will most likely be replaced by directories in `.../templates/bundles`.